# PyCharm doesn't start up

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I'm new to python community and intends to use PyCharm for django framework.

However, after installing PyCharm (32 bit launcher same as my OS), the software 
can't be launched.

After double-click the pycharm icon nothing happens, also tried on pycharm.exe, pycharm.bat, and pycharm64.exe, they all failed to start.

Have tried to search about the system requirement and I believe everything fits.

My OS is 32x bit, 4gb RAM and 100+gb storage available.

Hope anyone could give me hints about this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: try to reinstall; what OS you are using? may be have to use 'run as'. I'm using pycharm for years it worked on winxp and win7, never had problems.

Comment: When you go to the Task Manager do you see any process appearing? Also something might have gone wrong in one of your installations and something in the temp `C:\Users\...\<Pycharm folder>\system\tmp` is preventing the software from starting. Go there, delete everything inside, and try running again.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but are you sure your OS is 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys! 
Apparently the problem was I once set a vm ram size (also in system environment) which limits Pycharm to start.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner too in Python 3.7 and Pycharm 2019.3.1 Community Edition
[Pycharm 2019.3.1 Community Edition Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imhwZ.png)
I have the initial startup issue from Pycharm. IT was working for quite a while after the first installation. Then Pycharm is not starting up. As the solution described in many posts previously found that reinstall with complete removal may solve the problem.

I did that. But it happened all over again. Finally i digged into the tool and found that the Java Runtime or SDK is not at all available in my pc. I installed Java version (Java SE Development Kit 13 - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk13-downloads-5672538.html) and added the path to the Environment variables.

Make sure the command prompt shows the new path. And start Pycharm as attached.

[Commmand Prompt to start PyCharm Community Edition2019.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWwkY.png)

This worked for me. Eventhough double clicking the icon is still not working. Need to find out. Hope this helps to you.